# How to get rect position of cropped image

Tags: android

I need to find rect(x1,y1,x2,y2)position of cropped image from original image.
I am using com.android.camera.action.CROP to crop image.

[image]

Comment: Android does not have a "default crop intent": http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: Is this possible by using one of these libraries?

Comment: I have no idea, as I have not gone looking for this feature. My point is that you should not be relying upon a "default crop intent" that will not work on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you just collect the corner positions of the cropped image? You can use `View.getLocationOnScreen()` or `getLocationInWindow()`